# How To Auto Click QPushButton on QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to auto click and refresh QTextBrowser. But can't figure it out how. My codes are below.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap pix_w ("/home/pi/Downloads/wifi.png");
    QPixmap pix_s ("/home/pi/Downloads/laser.png");
    QPixmap pix_m ("/home/pi/Downloads/main.png");
    ui->label->setPixmap(pix_w);
    ui->label_2->setPixmap(pix_s);
    ui->label_5->setPixmap(pix_m);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QFile file("/home/pi/Desktop/test1.txt");
        if(!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
            QMessageBox::information(0,"info",file.errorString());

        QTextStream in(&file);

        ui->textBrowser->setText(in.readAll());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Once you have a pointer to your QPushButton, you can call [click()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#click) on it; or if you'd like to see the button visually animate, as if the user had clicked on it (in addition to emitting its `clicked()` signal), you can call [animateClick()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#animateClick) on it instead.

Answer (score 0):

a slot is nothing else as a method, you can call it in the same MainWindows class
and it will do the same logic as you were clicking the button